# How are angle characters being added to this button's text with CSS on hover?

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I came across the following code on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_animate1). It has a hover effect; when you hover over the button, it becomes **Hover>>** and the last two characters, >>, are automatically added when hovered over. I don't see any HTML code for that. Where did it come from? Does it have a separate code in HTML/CSS? I mean, there is no "text" for >> whereas there *is* text for "Hover"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Hover </span></button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS rules for pseudo-elements must have a content property or they simply don't appear in the page. In most cases it's an empty string because the thing doesn't contain text and is styled in other ways. In this case it actually contains an HTML entity code.

```css
.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb'; /* <-- Here's your huckleberry. */
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

[Here's the list](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references)

To use that character directly in your HTML you'd use its name with an ampersand: `&raquo;`

Comment: Thanks! Can I not put the >> in the body of HTML?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you plan on having it show and hide like it currently does?

Answer (score 3):

The "magic lines" are the two lines:

```
.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
```

The HTML code 00bb is the character ».